# I want to see all the running processes in android

Tags: android, performance, process, taskmanager

I want to display all the current running processes running on the andoid device in a textview. Can anyone assest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ActivityManager to get a list of running tasks:

```
ActivityManager actM = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> listm = actM.getRunningTasks(100);
```

Here is documentation for everything you can do with the list that is returned:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html